# Selecting with shadow

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have specific task - I need to edit image after picker to round like style with scaling. But i must have view controller that shadows all not-round part of image and have possibility to change round position. How can I do selected cicle not-shadowed and all other parts of image with black shadow?

P.S. It must [looks like this](http://goo.gl/z48DT).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a Image which has a round transparent circle area at the center(.png) an rest is black/grey.

You can actually add a mask(the above image with alpha{0.5 or less} you desire.) to the layer(CALayer) of the imageView you are showing to edit.

Comment: I need possibility dynamically change mask position at touch. Now i have mask with black round. How I can invert it in app?